# how to edit fields which are stored in textfile using classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I have two fields which are taken in two variables that are `StrcategoryName` and `StrcategoryUrl` means category name is stored in `StrcategoryName` and url is stored in `StrcategoryUrl` which are come from text file and then bind to input type text
now i want two edit these data in textfile,

which are stored in text file. Now I want to edit these two fields

```
<tr>
   <th align="left" valign="middle" class="text" scope="row"><b>Enter Category Name:</b></th>
   <td align="left" valign="middle"><input type="text" name="txtcategoryname" value="<%=StrcategoryName%>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th align="left" valign="middle" class="text" scope="row"><b>Enter Url Of Category Image :</b></th>
   <td align="left" valign="middle"><input type="text" name="txtName" value="<%=StrcategoryUrl%>"/></td>
</tr>
```

I have tried following code but I am getting an error.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific please?

Answer (score 0):

Text manipulation is not easy, because it's always treated as a collection of lines that we need to parse line by line or know exactly what line holds what ... and someone come along and change the order ... it's not pretty!

That is why we always use **XML** to store data into files as the Framework gives us much more control on what is stored and it's easy to remove, edit, insert or delete something.

in Classic ASP, you have several tutorials that help you read and write XML files all over the web and several questions here at SO.

> [Asp XML Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94689/asp-xml-parsing)
>
> [ASP Classic - XML Dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892161/asp-classic-xml-dom)

and one from my [favorite site](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202742/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com) back the days

> [Accessing XML Data using ASP](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020113639/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/101200-1.shtml)

Comment: its not a xml file i have used .txt file the how can i read and edit and then update and then save perticular data in that text file

Comment: I know, but you're going to end up with problems, it's better to use something that will avoid problems in the future. If you still think Text Files are the best approach, there are plenty of tutorials out there, this forum is to help, not to do work for you. [Try this for example](http://google.com/?q=classic+asp+text+file+read+write)

Comment: you r right but i am uploading that page through ftp and ftp does not support to xml files anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "**Scripting.FileSystemObject**" to read/write textfiles using ASP. Most of the examples you will find on the web show you the contents of these text files by using **Response.Write** to display the values.

One of the better sites for learning how to read/write textfiles files is located [here](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/files/directories-fso/could-i-get-some-help-working-with-files-using-filesystemobject.html).

It sounds like you need to do for 4 things:
1. Read the text file using the **Scripting.FileSystemObject** and store the data into ASP variables
2. Place these variables into an HTML form that posts to an update page
3. On the update page obtain the updated values using the **Request** object
4. Save these new values to the text file using the **Scripting.FileSystemObject**